# How to start Cassandra on a (M1) Macbook?

Tags: cassandra, apple-m1

I can't get Cassandra (3.11.10) to start on my Macbook with M1 chip. It gives the following error messages:

```
ERROR [main] 2021-07-09 13:12:46,807 NativeLibraryDarwin.java:64 - Failed to link the C library against JNA. Native methods will be unavailable.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/tom/apache-cassandra-3.11.10/tmp/jna8890560385007025439.tmp: dlopen(/Users/tom/apache-cassandra-3.11.10/tmp/jna8890560385007025439.tmp, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/tom/apache-cassandra-3.11.10/tmp/jna8890560385007025439.tmp: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
        /Users/tom/apache-cassandra-3.11.10/tmp/jna8890560385007025439.tmp: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

I'm using OpenJDK 1.8.0_292 (Azul Zulu).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found that replacing the JNA jar in Cassandra's `lib` directory (for example `apache-cassandra-3.11.10/lib/jna-4.2.12.jar`) with the latest (5.8.0, from `https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna/5.8.0/jar`) fixes the problem. At least just to get a development environment going.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work fine. A very simple and effective solution!

Comment: works as well on an M2 Macbook and with Cassandra 3.11.15

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the JNA (v4.2.2) JAR which ships with Cassandra 3.11 (and 4.0 soon) does not include the patch which allows builds for Apple M1's Darwin arm64 (see [JNA PR #1238](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/pull/1238)).

At the time of writing, there isn't a workaround available but if you just want to try using Cassandra, you can launch a Cassandra database on [Astra](http://dtsx.io/3mw14tX) on the free-tier and it doesn't require a credit card. It comes bundled with [Stargate.io](https://stargate.io/) -- a data access platform which allows you to connect to a Cassandra cluster using REST API, GraphQL API or JSON/Doc API so you can build an app immediately without having to download/install/configure Cassandra.

Alternatively, you can try [K8ssandra.io](http://k8ssandra.io/) -- a cloud-native distribution of Cassandra that runs on Kubernetes with all the tools bundled in for automated repairs, backups, monitoring with Prometheus + Grafana, and [Stargate.io](https://stargate.io/). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For cassandra-4.0.1 on M1 use jna-5.10.0 to replace the jna jar. You can get that jar if you have maven installed and execute

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.10.0
```

then you can find the jar in ~/.m2/repostory/net/java/dev/jna